Using fine-gray regression on mids object created with mice()
I am trying to fit a Fine-Gray regression model on a multiple imputed dataset created with mice() and was wondering how to do it with the finegray() function.
I used code found in cant get crr() Fine-Gray model to work on imputed data using mice() in R (Cov1/model.matrix-problem?)
which is :

library(survival)
library(mice)
library(cmprsk)
test1 <- as.data.frame(list(time=c(4,3,1,1,2,2,3,5,2,4,5,1, 4,3,1,1,2,2,3,5,2,4,5,1), 
                            status=c(1,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,1,1,2,0, 1,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,1,1,2,0),
                            x=c(0,2,1,1,NA,NA,0,1,1,2,0,1, 0,2,1,1,NA,NA,0,1,1,2,0,1),
                            sex=c(0,0,0,NA,1,1,1,1,NA,1,0,0, 0,0,0,NA,1,1,1,1,NA,1,0,0)))


sapply(test1, class)
test1[sapply(test1, is.character)] <- lapply(test1[sapply(test1, is.character)], as.factor)

dat <- mice(test1,m=10, seed=1982)



#Fine-Gray model

## create loopable list with imputed data  ##

longdat <- complete(dat, action='long', inc=TRUE) #long format for creating a list containing both original data and imputed

longdatsplit <- split(longdat, longdat$.imp) # split into imputed n to make individual vectors 

longdatlist <- list()   

for(i in 1:length(longdatsplit)) {             ##  for making list to able loop
  longdatlist[[i]] <- longdatsplit[[i]]
}

longdatlist2 <- longdatlist[- 1] #first row are non-imputed data, thus containing one more level than imputed data. 


### analysis-loop using list ###

mod <- list(analyses=vector("list", dat$m))

for(i in 1:dat$m){
  
covariates <- model.matrix(~longdatlist2[[i]]$x + longdatlist2[[i]]$sex , data = longdatlist2[[i]])[,-1]
  
  
mod$analyses[[i]] <- crr(ftime=longdatlist2[[i]]$time, fstatus=longdatlist2[[i]]$status,  cov1=covariates, failcode=1, cencode=0, variance=TRUE)

}

### Create as.mira ###

obj <- as.mira(mod)   

obj <- list(call=mod$analyses[[1]]$call, call1=dat$call, nmis=dat$nmis, analyses=mod$analyses) ## all calls originates form correct source, same as with-command

oldClass(obj) <- "mira"

summary(obj)
pool(obj)

summary(pool(obj))

However, when creating a new dataset where sex and x have 0 missing, I noticed the estimates using the code above do not correspond to the estimates using the code below, which it should? Using my data with different variables, the estimate differs as: -0.11479 vs -0.11408. Although not much its still a difference and the crr() function takes hours longer than the finegray() function.

mod <- crr(ftime=dat$time, fstatus=dat$status,  cov1=covariates, failcode=1, cencode=0, variance=TRUE)

I therefore wonder how to alter the code so that it works with the finegray() function? My attempt is clearly wrong (the data from the finegray() function does not even get stored properly):

mod <- list(analyses=vector("list", dat$m))
fg_data <- list(data=vector("list", dat$m))

for(i in 1:dat$m){
  
fg_data$data[[i]] <- finegray(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + x, id=id, data=longdatlist2[[i]])
  
mod$analyses[[i]] <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex+x, id=id, data=fg_data$data[[i]]

}


*Note I have the id variable in the original data (not in example).
